# JQM Nested Popups

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having a hard time with the new Alpha release of JQM not showing nested popups.  For example, I am displaying a popup form that the user is supposed to fill out, if the server side validation fails, I want to display an error popup.  I am finding that the error popup is not being shown.  I suspect that it is being shown below the original popup.

```
function bindSongWriterInvite() {

    // Bind the click event of the invite button
    $("#invite-songwriter").click(function () {
        $("#songwriter-invite-popup").popup("open");
    });

    // Bind the invitation click event of the invite modal
    $("#songwriter-invite-invite").click(function () {
        if ($('#songwriter-invite').valid()) {
            $('#songwriter-invite-popup').popup('close');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                async: true,
                url: '/songwriter/jsoncreate',
                data: $('#songwriter-invite').serialize() + "&songName=" + $("#Song_Title").val(),
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.state != "success") {
                        alert("Should be showing error dialog");
                        mobileBindErrorDialog(response.message);
                    }
                    else {
                        mobileBindErrorDialog("Success!");
                    }
                },
                failure: function () {
                    mobileBindErrorDialog("Failure!");
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        }
    });

    // Bind the cancel click event of the invite modal
    $("#songwriter-invite-cancel").click(function () {
        $("#songwriter-invite-popup").popup("close");
    });
}

function mobileBindErrorDialog(errorMessage) {
    // Close all open popups.  This is a work around as the JQM Alpha does not
    // open new popups in front of all other popups.
    var error = $("<div></div>").append("<p>" + errorMessage + "</p>")
                                .popup();
    $(error).popup("open");
}
```

So, you can see that I attempt to show the error dialog regardless of whether the ajax post succeeds or fails.  It just never shows up.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Mike

Comment: Interestingly I attempted to add a javascript alert to the anonymous div that is my error dialog and the alert displayed.  Just didn't show the dialog.

Comment: You can't nest popups can you?  Check out the very bottom of the [jQuery manual page for popups](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/).

Comment: Ok.  But shouldn't I be able to close the open popup and display a new one?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

I set a delay on the bindErrorPopup function to wait until the popup close animation completes.

```
function mobileBindErrorDialog(errorMessage, delay) {
    var error = $("<div></div>").attr({
        'data-rel': "popup",
        'data-theme': "a"
    });

    $(error).append("<p>" + errorMessage + "</p>")
            .popup({
                overlayTheme: "a",
                positionTo: "window",
                theme: "a"
            });

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(error).popup("open");
    }, delay);
}
```

Works awesome!